# C# Read multiple rows from different columns sharing same Foreign key SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, data-retrieval

I want an efficient way to retrieve all info that shares the same Foreign key in a table, and store the data in list/array.

I can read several rows from one column:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

int idForeignKey = inputIdFkey //Implemented on the WebPage for testing purposes

List<string> result = new List<string>();
string oString = "Select Column from Table where foreignKey = @fKey";

conn.Open();
SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, conn);
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fKey", idForeignKey);
using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (oReader.Read())
    {
        result.Add(oReader.GetString(0));
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

And I can read several columns if I am targeting one specific row:

```
int sqlData1;
int sqlData2;
int sqlData3;

string oString = "Select * from Table where TableID = @tId";
SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, conn);
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tId", 1001);
conn.Open();
using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (oReader.Read())
    {
        sqlData1 = oReader["Row1"].ToString();
        sqlData2 = oReader["Row2"].ToString();
        sqlData3 = oReader["Row3"].ToString();
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

But I would love to be able to read all/specific data that has the same foreign key. So I want to be able to retrieve several rows, save them to a list, and retrieve several other row data from a different column that shares the same foreign key.

I imagine it to be something like this:

```
int idForeignKey = inputIdFkey //Implemented on the WebPage for testing purposes

List<int> intList = new List<int>();
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();

string oString = "Select * from Table where ForeignKey = @fKey";

conn.Open();
SqlCommand oCmdSleep = new SqlCommand(oString, conn);
oCmdSleep.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fKey", idForeignKey);
using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmdSleep.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (oReader.Read())
    {
        intList.Add(oReader["Column1"].GetDateTime(0));
        dstringList.Add(oReader["Column3"].GetDateTime(0));
        dateList.Add(oReader["Column4"].GetDateTime(0));
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

But this does not working... Please advice me

Comment: In your third code snippet, what is `retSleep`?

Comment: @steve16351 It's not visible in the snippet but it must be a SQL query, which means `oString` isn't being used.

Comment: @steve16351 My bad on generalizing the code, it is suposed to be oString(changed it)

Comment: The code doesn't compile and doesn't make sense, for example you're calling `GetDateTime(0)` on all three "columns", where 0 is the column ordinal. `GetDateTime(0)` has to be called directly on the `SqlDataReader` with the corresponding column ordinal, and you wouldn't use that for a string or integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to give the name of the column, simply use the already established index:

```
int idForeignKey = inputIdFkey //Implemented on the WebPage for testing purposes

List<int> intList = new List<int>();
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();

string oString = "Select * from Table where ForeignKey = @fKey";

conn.Open();
SqlCommand oCmdSleep = new SqlCommand(oString, conn);
oCmdSleep.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fKey", idForeignKey);
using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmdSleep.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (oReader.Read())
    {
        intList.Add(oReader.GetDateTime(0));
        dstringList.Add(oReader.GetDateTime(3));
        dateList.Add(oReader.GetDateTime(4));
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

Here is a breakdown:

```
listVariable.Add(oReader.GetDataType("Index of column"));
```

This way you get to retrieve all row data for shared foreign key and the option to do so for as many columns as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) it would simplify mapping your query result to `List<T>`.

Add Dapper to your project using nuget.

`Install-Package Dapper -Version 1.50.5`

Add using for Dapper at the top of your class where you are running the query.

```
using Dapper;
```

Add a class that matches the structure of your query results. There are ways to do this using a script or utility app. [Here's an app for that.](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/12/11/sqlqueryresults-code-generation.aspx)

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then where you run the query do so like this.

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
   var MyList = conn.Query<MyClass>(@"select * from Table where ForeignKey = @fKey", 
       new { fKey = "SomeKey" }).ToList();
}
```

Once the query runs, you can then iterate across MyList.

```
foreach (var myItem in MyList)
{
    // Do something with myItem
}
```

If you want to bind the results, simply remove `.ToList()` from the end of the query as its default is `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: Why not use EF instead?

Comment: EF has its place, but for small projects it's overkill. If you need to drive a tack is a sledgehammer appropriate? Also, in most situations Dapper is twice as fast as EF. https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#performance

Comment: So if it is a small project why not roll your own methods to load up your objects?

Comment: A microORM is a middle ground of some ORM features without the overhead of the ORM tool like EF and not rolling your own CRUD methods and object mapping.

Comment: Will have to look into this( but there is a way simpler simpler and easy solution)

Comment: @Sondre Give it a try when you have a moment. I came up doing things the same way you are doing so now, because there was no other way to do it then - circa late 90s. I recommend learning Dapper, It really does simplify data access, and is far less complicated than EF for small projects. It is created and used by stackoverflow.